# Python Multiindexing and custom sorting

Tags: python, pandas, poker

I have a pandas series (edit: whoops meant dataframe) as shown here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9vnh.png)

I have two questions. First, what is the syntax to display/return all winning hands where Players at Table = 4, and Players to Showdown = 2?

Secondly, I am trying to then sort the "winning hand" values in order of their poker strength. Would I have to create a custom sort algorithm for this, where I would pre-code information such as King pair  > Jack pair? I'm not really sure what the most efficient way to go about this is.

Comment: We hate pictures. They're gross. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Poker hand evaluation algorithms typically return a single integer that classifies the hand into one of the 7462 hand values that is easy to compare and sort. Converting that into text for display is a separate operation. Text is for humans. Computers use numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a DataFrame, not a Series. Try

```
df.loc[4, 2]
```

Your second question is more complicated, and might warrant its own SO question. Please post code instead of images!